# Jquery - Flash Text

Tags: jquery, html

Can anyone suggest a way to make a nice text flashing effect using Jquery?

I have a counter that counts up to a dynamic percentage on page load - I would like the final figure to flash when it reaches its result - just wondered if anyone could suggest a nice smooth approach?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle or http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is nice and easy solution:](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Fcd/)

Call `effectFadeIn('test');` function with class name you want to flash.

```
var speed = 200;

function effectFadeIn(classname) {
    $("." + classname).fadeOut(speed).fadeIn(speed, effectFadeOut(classname))
}

function effectFadeOut(classname) {
    $("." + classname).fadeIn(speed).fadeOut(speed, effectFadeIn(classname))
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    effectFadeIn('test');
});​
```